# Symfony2 Sonata Userbundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

8 installed with SonataAdminBundle, the admin area is working well, and I'm on the stage to install SonataUserBundle which is installed in src/Application. Everything is looking good, but when I try to force doctrine:schema:update I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown column type "json" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the
  known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database t
  ypes for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is
   empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

I found too many solutions on the forums and here, but none of them is working.

Here is my AppKernel.php registered Bundles:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
    new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
    new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
    new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
    new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
    new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
    new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
    );
```

and here is my config.yml configuration:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

# Sonata FOSUser
sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
sonata_block:
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, first I have this configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"
```

and after this I redeclare:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

the two must be merged like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"
```